# How can I copy a range of data in excel (B2:B15) down with openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm a Python beginner and I made a script to extract data into an xlsx file with openpyxl but I'm stuck with a problem which seems pretty easy. I'd like to copy(not move) the  yellow data to the green cells in the following Excel file: [image: 1]

Or said in another way, I want to copy B2:B15 to B16:B29 within my python script. I don't need help with the import of openpyxl or creation of my ws it´s just the specific code that allows to copy the B2:B15 to B16:B29 which I don't get.

I appreciate any help! Ty so much.

I tried the following which didn´t work at all:

```
for row in range(16,29):
    for col in range(1,2):
        char = get_column_letter(col)
        ws[char + str(row)] = ws(['B2:B15'].value)
```

Comment: This is a repeat of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `ws` is your worksheet, then the code to do that is...

```
for row in range(16,30):
    ws.cell(row=row, column=2).value = ws.cell(row=row-14, column=2).value
```

Updated below for doing this multiple times

```
Repeat = 5  #Indicate how many times you want to paste the 15 rows
for cycle in range(1, Repeat+1):
    for row in range(14):
        ws.cell(row=row+2+(cycle)*14, column=2).value = ws.cell(row=row+2, column=2).value
```

Comment: thank you very much, very usefull and solved my issue. I market at answered but sadly can't upvote yet since I'm new. Something that would interest me is if there is a way to copy that same range many times below without copy and pasting that same code for different ranges. Greetings

Comment: Updated new code which will repeat the 'paste' as many times as is the value of ````Repeat````